# How can use social share button for NEXTJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, facebook-social-plugins

I want to use social share button for nextjs project so I am use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-share but not work very well for exapmle share cout for facebook and linkedin and twitter nothing to show and I want to show total share count which does not have this option
How can I use https://donreach.com/social-share-count/ for nextjs project?

Comment: Can you explain more on what problems you are having using react-share that make it "not work very well"?

Comment: @CharleyBodkin edited

Comment: If you can find an API that will give you social share counts from a given URL, you can make a request to it from a JS function, and get the data back. You can call this JS function from getInitialProps, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can find an API that will give you social share counts from a given URL, you can make a request to it from a JS function, and get the data back. You can call this JS function from getInitialProps.

See: "Data Fetching: getInitialProps | Next.js" https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps

Taken from the docs:

```
function Page({ stars }) { 
  return <div>Next stars: {stars}</div> 
} 

Page.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => { 
  const res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/next.js');
  const json = await res.json();
  return { stars: json.stargazers_count }
}

 export default Page
```

Comment: did u meet the problem that using react-share, cause the meta, title, undefined? https://gyazo.com/b8665d45c386929b3d0119435a02bf24